# Ansible - multiple statements with the same variables

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible, so I might be missing something obvious. I have a playbook doing the following:

```
- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" comment="{{item.user_description}}" home="/home/{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
  with_items:
    - { user_name: "user1", user_description: "user 1", user_id: "2000" }
    - { user_name: "user2", user_description: "user 2",  user_id: "2001" }

- name: Copy SSH keys
  copy:
    src: "keys/{{ item.user_name }}.key"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.user_name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    owner: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    group: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    mode: 0600
  with_items:
     - { user_name: "user1", user_description: "user 1", user_id: "2000" }
     - { user_name: "user2", user_description: "user 2",  user_id: "2001" }
```

Basically reusing the `with_items` over and over again. Ideally I would like to store this in an external file with all the fields I'm likely to use.

Is this possible? Where should I start looking?

Ta....
Tom

Answer (score 10):

> I'm new to ansible

I'm listing here some different options, so you can learn a bit more than just the ideal solution (Option 5)

**Option 1: Use YAML anchors and references**

This is completely unrelated to Ansible but since the files are in YAML format you're able to do something like this:

```
- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" comment="{{item.user_description}}" home="/home/{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
  with_items: &my_items
    - user_name: user1
      user_description: user 1
      user_id: 2000
    - user_name: user2
      user_description: user 2
      user_id: 2001

- name: Copy SSH keys
  copy:
    src: "keys/{{ item.user_name }}.key"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.user_name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    owner: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    group: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    mode: 0600
  with_items: *my_items
```

**Option 2: Variables in blocks**

Blocks are a feature introduced in Ansible 2. You can define variables for blocks and use them in the contained tasks

```
- vars:
    userlist:
      - user_name: user1
        user_description: user 1
        user_id: 2000
      - user_name: user2
        user_description: user 2
        user_id: 2001
  block:
    - name: Create real users
      user: name="{{item.user_name}}" comment="{{item.user_description}}" home="/home/{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
      with_items: "{{ userlist }}"

    - name: Copy SSH keys
      copy:
        src: "keys/{{ item.user_name }}.key"
        dest: "/home/{{ item.user_name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        owner: "{{ item.user_name }}"
        group: "{{ item.user_name }}"
        mode: 0600
      with_items: "{{ userlist }}"
```

**Option 3: Apply the loop to an `include` task and have your tasks in the included file**

```
- include: other_file.yml
  with_items:
    - user_name: user1
      user_description: user 1
      user_id: 2000
    - user_name: user2
      user_description: user 2
      user_id: 2001
```

In the included file you will be able to access the item and its properties, e.g. `item.user_name`, just like you already had it:

```
- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" comment="{{item.user_description}}" home="/home/{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"

- name: Copy SSH keys
  copy:
    src: "keys/{{ item.user_name }}.key"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.user_name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    owner: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    group: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    mode: 0600
```

**Option 4: set a fact containing your user list in a separate task**

```
- set_fact:
    userlist:
      - user_name: user1
        user_description: user 1
        user_id: 2000
      - user_name: user2
        user_description: user 2
        user_id: 2001

- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" comment="{{item.user_description}}" home="/home/{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
  with_items: "{{ userlist }}"

- name: Copy SSH keys
  copy:
    src: "keys/{{ item.user_name }}.key"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.user_name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    owner: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    group: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    mode: 0600
  with_items: "{{ userlist }}"
```

**Option 5: Use group_vars**

**group_vars** probably make the most sense here. I guess your hosts are in some group in your inventory file, let's call it `foo`.

Create a file `group_vars/foo` relative to your playbook with the content:

```
userlist:
  - user_name: user1
    user_description: user 1
    user_id: 2000
  - user_name: user2
    user_description: user 2
    user_id: 2001
```

All hosts which belong to the group `foo` will now automatically have access to the `userlist` variable. And you can just use it in your tasks:

```
- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" comment="{{item.user_description}}" home="/home/{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
  with_items: "{{ userlist }}"

- name: Copy SSH keys
  copy:
    src: "keys/{{ item.user_name }}.key"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.user_name }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    owner: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    group: "{{ item.user_name }}"
    mode: 0600
  with_items: "{{ userlist }}"
```

If you don't have groups or don't want to limit it to certain groups, you can store the vars file as `group_vars/all` where all hosts have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for such a complete answer. In the end I discovered I could use with_dict like this:

1) Create a vars.yml file (in the same directory)

```
---
usersxxx:
    user1:
      description: User1
      user_id: 2001
      shell: /bin/bash
      ...other options here
    user2:
      description: User2        
      user_id: 2002
      shell: /bin/bash
      ...other options here
```

2) Create the new playbook:

```
---
- hosts: home
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  become: yes

  tasks: 
    - name: Create real users
      user: name="{{item.key}}" comment="{{item.value.description}}" home="/home/{{item.key}}" uid="{{item.value.user_id}}"
      with_dict: "{{usersxxx}}"
```

Looks like it works perfectly.

I only changed it to usersxxx to ensure that I wasn't hitting any python/ansible primitives.

Hope this helps someone else!